# IPtables logging not working

Tags: iptables

I have set up a simple iptable that should log all dropped packages to a file. When I check my log file it is empty.

My iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             #Allow loopback
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And in `/etc/rsyslog.d/90-iptables.conf` I redirect the messages to another file:

```
:msg,contains,"IPTables-Dropped: " /var/log/iptables.log"
```

Now changed into

```
kern.warning      /var/log/iptables.log
```

Output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` yields:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   58254 11751250 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3937   232480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
      52     2824 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
      68     3696 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
     114     9187 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1636   154417 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
      16      668 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70233 packets, 16508738 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1641   154653 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
    1640   154613 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Would you be willing to edit your question to show the output for `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` instead? That would give us a more complete picture, and also show the packets counters, so that we can see if the LOGGING chain was actually traversed and how many times.

Comment: Added the requested output. But with options you gave I only got the version but if I removed the -V i got more output.

Comment: lower case "v". I want to see the packet / byte counters and the interfaces. Particularly for your "allow loopback" line.

Comment: Ahh, updated again with the info.

Comment: If you take out any of your attempts to redirect the log output, do the log entries then appear in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log`, as is the default?

Comment: It adds to /var/log/syslog booth with and without the redirect

Answer (score 1):

By convention, only files ending in `.conf` in `/etc/rsyslog.d` are looked at by `rsyslogd`. The default `/etc/rsyslogd.conf` file contains this:

```
#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

The recommendation is to change the file name from `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.log` to `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf`. However, consider to further follow convention and include a load order prefix similar to the other files in that directory. i.e. `/etc/rsyslog.d/90-iptables.conf`

Note: I tested `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf`, and it works fine.

Comment: That was typo from me. It was allready named `iptables.conf` but i hace not chaged it to `90-iptables.conf`but all output is still placed in `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it doesn't have an accepted answer, or correct answer as far as I can see. It's do with the order in which the log config files are loaded in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/` directory.

I fixed it by prepending my `iptables.conf` file with `10-` so the file name then reads:

`10-iptables.conf`

This loads it as a higher priority than the `50-defaults.conf` file in the same directory, which I assume is overring the behaviour in your iptables log config and directing the logging to the default file location of `/var/logs/syslog`.

It loads these configs in the alphabetical order so by numbering them you can configure the load priority. The files all need to have the `.conf` prefix though, because that is what `rsyslog` looks for when loading log configs.

Answer (score 0):

That is because they are logged from the kernel.

You need to change to this in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
kern.warning      /var/log/iptables.log
```

Comment: I changed conf and restarted my rsyslog. Still nothing in the file but I can see them in /var/log/syslog

Comment: @Olof Try commenting out your line `:msg,contains...` and reload rsyslog

Comment: Allready did that.